# How do i hide parent elements if child <span> does not exist

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to hide any parent element who's child elements does not include a span tag with class required. For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
      <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      <span class="required">*</span>
      Title
      <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
   <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title">
</div>
<div class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
   <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      Title
   </label>
   <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title">
</div>
<div class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
   <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      Title
   </label>
   <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.optionfield').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('span.required').length == 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Proof is in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpGgQ/1/) ;)

Comment: OK. I'm officially impressed that i was able to get answer within minutes of posting it. Thanks a lot karthikr!

Answer (score 5):

A one-liner, but maybe not as efficient as other answers:

```
$('.optionfield:not(:has(span.required))').hide();
```

In action:

```js
$('.optionfield:not(:has(span.required))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
      <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      <span class="required">*</span>
      Title
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title" />

</li>
<div class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
   <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      Title
   </label>
    <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title" />
</div>
<div class="optionfield" id="fieldAdTitle">
   <label class="optionLabel" for="Title">
      Title
   </label>
    <input type="text" class="" value="" name="Title" id="Title" />
</div>
```

Also, you have some malformed HTML going on there: you've got two unclosed `<label>` tags in that first `<div>`.

Comment: That was a mistype on my part. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @JosephGarcia if you ask me this is the way to go and should have been accepted. The jQuery methods `:has` and `:not` are exactly invented for that purpose. `$('.optionfield` already returned a collection of all your elements, therefore no need to create an extra `.each()` function and do stuff in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
    $('.optionfield') //Get your sources
    .filter(function(){ //APply filter
          return $(this).find('span.required').length == 0}) // to get the elements with no span.required as child
    .hide(); //hide the filtered out ones.
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZJ4K/)

See **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest:

```
// hide them all:
$('.optionfield').hide()
// find the descendant elements:
.find('span.required')
// having found them, find the closest ancestor:
.closest('.optionfield')
// show them:
.show().
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).